# How to query the time in unix epoch timestamp in aws athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a simple table contains the **node, message, starttime, endtime** details where starttime and endtime are in unix timestamp. The query I am running is:

```
select node, message, (select from_unixtime(starttime)), (select from_unixtime(endtime)) from table1 WHERE try(select from_unixtime(starttime)) > to_iso8601(current_timestamp - interval '24' hour) limit 100
```

The query is not working and throwing the syntax error.

I am trying to fetch the following information from the table:

- query the table using start time and end time for past 'n' hours or 'n' days and get the output of starttime and endtime in human readable format
- query the table using a specific date and time in human readable format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need "extra" selects and you don't need `to_iso8601` in the where clasue:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       (1627409073, 1627409074),
       (1627225824, 1627225826)
 ) AS t (starttime, endtime))

SELECT from_unixtime(starttime), from_unixtime(endtime)
FROM
dataset
WHERE from_unixtime(starttime) > (current_timestamp - interval '24' hour) limit 100
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-27 18:04:33.000 | 2021-07-27 18:04:34.000 |

Comment: thank you. This solved my query. One more thing, can we modify the _col0 and _col1 to starttime and endtime respectiveely ?

Comment: @karthik yes, using [`as %alias%`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_as.asp) in the select statement. I would recommend you to go through some SQL tutorials, Athena supports ANSI-compatible SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

to search last week you can use

```
WHERE your_date >= to_unixtime(CAST(now() - interval '7' day AS timestamp))
```